# TypeORM: duplicate entry error after changing length of primary key

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I am making a table for an email with Nestjs, MySQL, and Typeorm. I have char type primary key length of 39, and have put a unique string made up of UUID concatenate with some extra sting in it.
Here is the way I make the primary key with Typeorm in Nestjs entity file named 'email'. There is no @PrimaryColumn or @PrimaryGeneratedColumn in it.

```
@Column({
  primary: true,
  type: 'char',
  length: 39,
})
id: string;
```

There were some data in the table. After I changed the length from 39 to 45 and run the server, an error happened at TypeOrmModule. I didn't try to save anything. It's strange that I have seen similar errors during inserting data thru googling.

```
QueryFailedError: Duplicate entry '' for key 'email.PRIMARY'
```

Even I set back the length to 39, still the error happens. The only way that I've found to run the server is by dropping the table and make a new one.

I have 2 questions about this error.

1. Is there a solution to change the length of the primary key, keep the data in the table, and run the server?
2. How '' - an empty string from the error sentence - affects the uniqueness of the primary key?

Comment: Do you have `synchronize` set to `true` in your Typeorm config object?

Comment: @hamidsajjadi yes I have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you have `synchronize: true` in your Typeorm config object.
And based on [Typeorm documents](https://typeorm.io/#/connection-options)

> Indicates if database schema should be auto created on every application launch. Be careful with this option and don't use this in production - otherwise you can lose production data.

So what actually happens is that when you change the length of a column and launch your application typeorm tries to sync this change and update your schema. And for the reasons mentioned [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3216#issuecomment-446890423), Typeorm does that by dropping the column entirely and creating a new one, where it encounters a duplicate error.

1. For your first question, you can use [migrations](https://typeorm.io/#/migrations) to have more control over how the schema is updated. Though I should mention that in migration typeorm behave similarly and drops the column for the change, but at least you can edit the migration file yourself to ensure it does what you want it to do. Or you can edit the schema of database directly. Whatever you choose to do, `synchronize` probably is never a good idea, except for the very early stages of development.
2. As your second question, since your primary column is a `char` with no default value, the new column values will be filled with `''` noramally, as default of `char` for fields that are not nullable; but obviously it encounters a duplicate error on a primary column where uniqueness is a most too; hence the error `Duplicate entry '' for key 'email.PRIMARY'`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So migration let me alter the table & alter the column while synchronize alter the table & add the column and it is the reason that ' ' will be filled for the existing data...

Comment: Yes. Migrations will create sql commands for you, and you can revise them and choose if you want to apply them to your db , so yes you can change them if needed. Synchronize does the same in the background without you knowing, as a result you won't have any control over it. And in this case it is removing and recreating the column to apply your changes.